# Matplotlib: Format colorbar of figure drawn within a fuction

Tags: function, matplotlib, padding, colorbar

In Python, I am using a module, e.g. `module1`, which contains a function, e.g. `func_calc_and_draw()`, that performs calculations with my input data and plots the results using `matplotlib`.
In the drawn plots, the colorbar overlays with the plot, so I want to increase the padding between the axes and the colorbar, but I do not want to change the code of `func_calc_and_draw()` in `module1`.

I can adapt some of the graphic's properties, e.g. the figure size and the distance between the plot and the legend, by using the `rc_context()` of matplotlib:

```
import module1 as m1
import matplotlib as mpl

with mpl.rc_context({'figure.fisize': (10,7), 'legend.borderaxespad': 4})
    fig = m1.func_calc_and_draw(my_data)
```

However, I have not found a hint how I can change the properties of the colorbar with `rc_context()`.
The function `func_calc_and_draw()` also returns a figure handler.
Is it possible to increase the padding of the colorbar with the handler?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Yes, but it will be much easier to simply fix `func_calc_and_draw` and better yet to decouple them - drawing and calculating should rarely be done in the same method.

Comment: Thank you for your post. However, I did not program `module1` and hence, I think it is better to leave it untouched.

Comment: Unfortunately without module1 we can't readily help you fix the problem.  If your question is if there is a rc context pad for colorbars, there is not - they are more complicated than that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to look for a workaround.